# webpacker のロード時に各変数を確認する方法

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack

`Webpacker` で呼び出されるコードのデバックはどのようにすればよいのでしょうか？

具体的には以下のような流れで問題に直面しました。

こちらのQiitaの記事を参考にRails+Vue.jsの勉強をしていたのですが
https://qiita.com/naoki85/items/51a8b0f2cbf949d08b11

記事内にもある通り`config/webpack/loaders/vue.js`にある

```
const extractCSS = !(inDevServer && (devServer && devServer.hmr)) || isProduction
```

を

```
const extractCSS = false
```

と書き換える必要がありました。

ただ元の記述も development 環境であれば`false`になるように見えるのに`true`になってしまっているのが気になり
`!inDevServer`, `!devServer`, `!devServer.hmr`を順番に`extractCSS`に代入して`!devServer.hmr`が`true`になってしまっている事まで確認しました。

ただ、毎回このように面倒な方法を取りたくないので`ruby`の`binding.pry`などのように変数の追跡を行う方法を知りたいのですが、どのように行えば良いでしょうか？